# Minted custom label and reference

Tags: cross-referencing, minted

I use minted for listing Objective-C code and I need to replace the label text from Listing 1. to `Source Code #chapter_number#.#subsection_number#.#subsubsection_number#.#label_number#` like "Source Code 2.2.2.1. Starting the accelerometer". Also, I need to refer this like "Source Code 2.2.2.1.".

How can I accomplish this?

I tried:

```
\usepackage{minted}
    \renewcommand\listingscaption{Source Code \thesubsection -}
```

But it isn't working when I try to use `\cref` or `\ref` or `\autoref` I got "listing 1 1".

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Shouldn't `caption_number` be `chapter_number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Source code}
\renewcommand{\thelisting}{\thesubsection.\arabic{listing}}
\crefname{listing}{source code}{source codes}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Ctitle}
\section{Stitle}
\subsection{Sstitle}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{objective-c}
Abc
\end{minted}
\caption{Caption}\label{list}
\end{listing}

References: \cref{list}, \ref{list}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That works as I imagined :). Thanks for your help.